# Storing and accessing AWS Cognito user data via service

Tags: angular, amazon-cognito

I am new to angular and trying to build a service that I can store the user's attributes from AWS Cognito. I have the function to get the user params working and returning the data I need. However, on the initial page load, the promise doesn't get returned until after the page has rendered.

How do I ensure the promise I call after login to get the user attrs is returned before I need to use it in a component?

Comment: I think that might defeat the purpose of Angular. And which version of Angular are you using? 1,2,4 or 5? (2-5 Is essentially the same thing with slight improvement on each).

Comment: Something that could be helpful to you: https://angular.io/guide/router#resolve-pre-fetching-component-data

Comment: @PraveenP angular . to shed more light on what I'm trying to do, once the user logs in we grab an id that associated events to that user. So the workflow should be: 1) get user's id (done right after login), 2) do get request using that id from the component, 3) return and display results. However, 2 is done before 1. You stated that might defeat the purpose of angular. I guess I'm doing something incorrectly so curious if you could tell me how I can do the above

Comment: @R.Richards thanks for that link. It seems close, but trying to grasp what's going on.

Comment: Well, Angular doesn't wait for the service calls to return data like PHP does, Angular simply put it in a queue and move on (Like Java threads). So you'll need to chain the workflow the way you want it to work. I.E. Component 2 should use if statement to check whether Component 1's data present, before rendering the component. That way soon as data receives Angular will render the Component 2.

Comment: Could you post how you're calling the component 1 and 2 at the moment?

Comment: I think that's my problem. I am calling it in a service once the user is logged in, but I probably need to call it from the component that uses it instead. I was trying to only do the GET request once and then use that data across multiple components. My hopes was that would allow me to have their user id and to display the logged in user's name at the top of the page. So I guess I need to make the service smart enough to know if I already have that data use it instead of sending another request to the backend.

Comment: Without any actual code, here's how I would do it. Create a service for storing user data (`StorageService`) then use `BehaviorSubject` to store the user data in the `StorageService`(Last set of data is kept until browser refreshed or new data assigned). Then set the values on from the `LoginComponent`. After that use variable with type `Subscription` (in any component that needs user information) and subscribe to the `BehaviorSubject` in the `StorageService` to check whether the user is logged in. If not use `navigateByUrl` of `Router` module to redirect back to login page.

Comment: You can use `navigateByUrl` in the login component to send the user on to the next component within the `subscribe` block of the service call to the AWS.